# DOM Not Found Error Confusion

Tags: php, dom

I do the following:

```
$container = $element->ownerDocument->createNode($tag);
if ( $anchor->hasChildNodes() && 
     is_object($anchor->lastChild) && 
     $anchor->lastChild->nodeName == 'span' && 
     $container->nodeName == 'span' ) {

        $anchor->parentNode->insertBefore($container, $anchor->lastChild);
}
```

(I realize that the is_object test is likely superfluous, but added it out of frustration) and on the insertBefore receive

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'
```

Comment: Not very clear - but as a guess `$anchor->parentNode->insertBefore($container, $anchor->parentNode->lastChild);`

Comment: I don't think so. The insert needs to be placed before the last child of $anchor, not the last child of the parent of $anchor.

The confusion is that all elements of the insertBefore exist...so I don't know what is not found.

Comment: Your trying to insertBefore based on the parentNode and then saying insert before the last sub node of the current node.  If so - remove the `->parentNode` from what you currently have

Comment: That's standard practice. If I have $b, and want to insert $a before it, having $b->parentNode->insertBefore($a, $b);

Comment: Correct - but your saying insertBefore `$b->lastChild`

Comment: ah! hmm...trying...

Comment: Bravo! Please put it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempting to insert an element based on the parentNode, but inserting it before the lastChild.  This is one generation apart.

So instead of..

```
 $anchor->parentNode->insertBefore($container, $anchor->lastChild);
```

it should be...

```
 $anchor->insertBefore($container, $anchor->lastChild);
```